# A closed form for $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}\ J_0(x)\ \sin\left(x\,\sqrt[3]{2}\right)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am stuck with this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}\ J_0(x)\ \sin\left(x\,\sqrt[3]{2}\right)}{x}dx,$$
where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

Is it possible to express this integral in a closed form (preferably, using elementary functions, Bessel functions, integers and basic constants)?

Comment: The first formula from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/397590/73025) will do the job.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Hint:* Use the formula $(79)$ from [this *MathWorld* page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html):
$$J_0(z)=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi e^{i\,z\cos\theta}\,d\theta$$
and then change the order of integration.

---

*Result:*
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}\ J_0(x)\ \sin\left(x\,\sqrt[3]2\right)}xdx=\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]4+\sqrt[3]{16}}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]4-\sqrt[3]{16}}}2$$